# Import CSV file into sqlite3 using Ruby script

Tags: ruby, csv, sqlite

I have a ruby script which will read data from some CSV file and import them into sqlite database.
I can do this task easily from console using  following command:

```
sqlite> .import <filename> <tablename>
sqlite> .import test.csv PROJECT_REPORT
```

How can I achieve the same form Ruby script ?

I am doing something similar like following(just a work arround):

```
 CSV.foreach("timelog.csv") do |row|
     database.execute("INSERT INTO PROJECT_REPORT(
     Date,User,Activity,Comment)
     values
    (#{row[0]}, '#{row[1]}', '#{row[2]}', '#{row[3]}') ")
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a one time job and you have a simple script that works why not stick with what you already have? If you need to grow the ruby script and want to expand it look at [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) (or on of the other ORMs) as an interface to your SQLite database. Create a simple class to contain your Date, User, Activiy and Comment fields and let DataMapper do the heavy lifting to the database.

**Updated with datamapper example**
Here's a simple pseudo-example the datamapper implementation. **This is not tested!**

```
#datamapper configuration here
#.
#.
class UserActivity
 include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,         Serial    
  property :log_date,       DateTime  
  property :user,       Text        
  property :activity    Text
  property :comment     Text
  property :created_at, DateTime
end
```

So to use it in your example above...

```
CSV.foreach("timelog.csv") do |row|
  userActivity = UserActivity.new( :log_date => row[0], :user => row[1], :activity => row[2], :comment => row[3])
  userActivity.save!
end
```

Obviously this isn't a complete solution, but it will get you started.

Comment: No this is not a 'one time job'. I need to read multiple, small csv file and persist them in sqlite3 database

Comment: Thanks a lot..and one more thing, in my csv file first line contains Column header and I skip that row.